# Example for Injective Homomorphism doesn't Mean Embedding

Tags: model-theory

I'm reading the article about model theory in Wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory

---

**Theorem**
Every embedding is an injective homomorphism, but the converse holds only if the signature contains no relation symbols, such as in groups or fields.

---

Is there a guick counterexample for the converse(injective homomorphism doesn't mean embedding). If possible, please write down the **injective homomorphism** and the **two structures** in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two structures s.t. $dom(A)=dom(B)=\{0,1\}$ and let $P$ be a unary predicate s.t. $P^A=\{0\}$ and $P^B=\{0,1\}$, then the identity function $id$ is an homomorphism but not an embedding, since $B\models P(f(1))$ but $A\not \models P(1)$.

In general a *homomorphism* is a map $f:A\to B$ s.t. for all atomic formulas $\phi$: $A\models \phi(a)$ entails $A\models \phi(f(a))$. *Embeddings* must also satisfy a back condition: for all atomic formulas $\phi$, $A\models \phi(a)$ if and only if $A\models \phi(f(a))$.

Comment: Thank you. I have mistaken the definition of homomorphism. Thank you for correcting my wrong opinion.